# MASM - Why doesn't this code cause the computer to beep?

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I've read about the code to make the computer beep but I can't get it to work. The following code asks the user to enter digits. The digits are displayed on the screen but if the user types a non-digit character it's supposed to beep. When I run the program and type a non-digit character, it just crashes.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

enterDigits     BYTE        'Please type some digits: ', 0

.code

main PROC

    mov EDX, OFFSET enterDigits
    call    WriteString

L1:</b>

    call    ReadChar
    cmp AL, 0Dh
    je  FINISHED
    cmp AL, 30h
    jl  BEEP
    cmp AL, 39h
    jg  BEEP
    call    WriteChar
    loop    L1  

BEEP:</b>

    mov AH, 02h
    mov DL, 07h
    int 21h
    jmp L1

FINISHED:</b>

    call    CRLF
    call    CRLF

exit</b>

main ENDP</b>

END main


If I replace BEEP with:

BEEP:</b>

    mov AL, 33h
    call    WriteChar
    jmp L1
```

It will print a 3 when you type a non-digit character. Don't know if that makes any difference or not.

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: Attempted to clean up the formatting a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source for WriteChar [here](http://www.cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/cse3101/examples/Lib32/Irvine32.asm), you can see that it is invoking the Windows API WriteConsole method rather than use an MSDOS API.  I believe you aren't going to be able to call a DOS API method because you're running in a mode incompatible with the kernel managing the hardware and I/O functions.

You might try adjusting the compatibility mode of your exe to use Windows 95 (right click on EXE, go to Compatibility tab).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. What you said went way over my head, however. I'm in an assembly language class and I wrote the rest of the code from what I've learned from the course textbook, but there isn't any mention of beeping, so that part of the  code is what I found after searching the Web. Is there some other way to make a beep? All our instructor said was to give the hint that the ascii code for a beep is 7.

Comment: When the instructor said that the ASCII code for beep is 7, it means that the intention is to print the code out to the console.  WriteChar with 33h prints out the ASCII '3' character.  So, in your second version of beep, put 07h in AL and let it call WriteChar.  I bet it beeps then.  Int 21h might have done the same thing long ago under MS-DOS, but you have to use the Windows API now.  WriteChar uses the Windows API.

Comment: Once again, thank you so much for responding. I originally tried your suggestion. The program didn't crash, but it didn't beep either. That's when I went looking on the Web. I changed it to 33h to see if that might help diagnose the problem. I did add back the original beep code and replaced 33h with 07h. Still doesn't beep, but doesn't crash either. Perhaps I should run it on a different computer. But before you ask the obvious, the sound is otherwise fine with my computer :)

Comment: You might try to open a command prompt and type "echo CTRL+G" (but press CTRL and G instead of typing it).  When you hit enter, it should beep.  This is similar to what you're trying to make the program do.

Comment: I became suspicious when CTRL-G didn't work, so I tried other computers. My original program, where I moved seven hex into AL and called WriteChar worked like a charm on the computers in the lab on campus. Now that makes me feel as though I've wasted your time. Thank you for all the help. If there is a next time, perhaps it will involve a more worthy question.

Comment: No problem at all.  It has been years since I've even looked at assembly, so it was a little fun.  The only dumb question is the one that remains un-asked.